# react hooks + websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

Implemented a chat app and used `websocket`. the problem is when the component does mount two connection is created instead of one and whenever a message sends it broadcasts twice. I almost know where the problem lies but don't know how to with it. This is my code and I think it's self-explanatory but if it needs more tell me please. Thanks for your instruction

```
function ChatScreen(props) {

    const client = useRef(null)
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const { classes } = props

    const location = useLocation()
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const { name, room } = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams])
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!location.search) {
            navigate("/")
            return;
        }
        client.current = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/' + room + '/')
        client.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
        client.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");

    }, [location, navigate, room])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!client.current) return;

        client.current.onmessage = (message) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
            console.log('got reply!');
            setMessages(m => [
                ...m,
                {
                    msg: data.message,
                    name: data.name,
                }
            ])
        }
    }, [])

    const sendMsgHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!client.current) {
            console.error('No functional connection is established!')
            return;
        }
        client.current.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                type: "message",
                message: value,
                name: name
            })
        );
        setValue('')
    }
    
    return (...)
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(ChatScreen)
```

I think the problem is with the dependency array of `useEffect` but if not, what is?

and a snapshot
[image]

Comment: Are you using React 18? If yes, see https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors

Comment: Also, the websocket has a dependency on room only. You can create another `useEffect` hook with room as dependency to initialize the web socket client. Another thing, you can `useEffect` cleanup method to close the connection when component is unmounted.

Comment: yes, I'm using v18. well, read the article but couldn't figure it out. about the second comment, gonna apply it and will share the result. thanks by the way

Comment: @user1672994 after separating `useEffect`s and useEffect cleanup method, it works as expected now. thanks a bunch

Comment: @user1672994 is there any more comprehensive documentation or example covering this?

Comment: Let me post the solution as answer with documentation links

Comment: I've posted the solution as answer. Please let me know if you require any additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UseEffect` hook executes when any of the dependency change. Currently

Since the websocket initialization requires only `room` params dependency so I would suggest to create a new useEffect hook with only required dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
        client.current = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/' + room + '/')
        client.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
        client.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");

    }, [room]);
```

Also, I would recommend you should define the `useEffect` with cleanUp method to dispose the websocket connection. The cleanup is inovked when component gets unmounted.

```
useEffect(() => {
            client.current = new W3CWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/' + room + '/')
            client.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
            client.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");
            return () => {
                client.current.close();
                 };
        }, [room]);
```

Read the details how useEffect works and comparison against class component life cycle events at [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: sure. based on your instruction my problem was twofold and applying this solved the problem. thanks